# How to set X-Forwarded-Proto to https on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a .NET 5.0 application on Elastic Beanstalk
I have a frontend listener on port 443, with an ssl certificate that works fine.
However in my .NET code if i check the X-Forwarded-Proto header it is always set to "http" even though the client sent the request over https ( which worked fine )

Any ideas what might be going on ?

Comment: If you haven't solved this problem, you should see my question/answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570998/why-is-x-forwarded-proto-always-set-to-http-on-elastic-beanstalk.