# Why is X-Forwarded-Proto always set to HTTP on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

### Setup

Hi. I'm deploying an ASP.Net Core application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The platform I'm running on is 64bit Amazon Linux 2/2.1.5 using Nginx as the proxy server software. I've got a pair of listeners for my load balancer set up in the environment configuration. They are set up as follows:

- `Port=443 Protocol=HTTPS SSL=certificate Process=default`
- `Port=80 Protocal=HTTP Process=default`

And I've got a single process:

`Name=default Port=80 Protocol=HTTPS`

### Problem

On my ASP.Net Core server, I'm trying to check if the original client to the server is communicating over HTTPS or HTTP. As I understand, the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header for requests should carry this information. However, the value of `X-Forwarded-Proto` is always `http` regardless of how a client connects to the server. **Why is the `X-Forwarded-Proto` not ever set to `https` even when connected as so from my web browser?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure Nginx isn't overriding that header when it forwards requests to your .NET service?

Comment: @MarkB From what I understand, it's not. Here's the relevant setting in the Nginx config file: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: That line in your Nginx config file is literally doing the exact thing you say it is not. It is taking the scheme that was used to connect to Nginx (your load balancer connects to Nginx using HTTP) and setting that as the `X-Forwarded-Proto`, overwriting anything that the load balancer may have set in that header.

Comment: @MarkB Ok. So that implies that `$scheme` being set based solely on the communication between load balancer and Nginx. The load balancer should be sending a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header though. Does `$scheme` not consider that header?

Comment: No, `$sheme` is literally just the protocol that was used to connect to Nginx. You should delete that entire line from your Nginx config to allow the header to pass through, or else do something like what is documented [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)

Comment: @MarkB Yep, you are completely right. It took a little while to actually replace the config on the AWS server. I wouldn't never thought it was the problem so thanks for pointing it out. It's weird that this very basic AWS setup doesn't automatically forward the correct header in its default Nginx config.

Comment: I don't think it's weird at all. You shouldn't make assumptions that Nginx will somehow detect it's running on AWS and "do the right thing". You simply need to be aware of how the settings you configure Nginx with are actually going to work.

Comment: @MarkB. Right, I get that. It's just that this particular configuration was not my own. It was a defaults set up by AWS specifically for Elastic Beanstalk which is always run behind a load balancer. That's why I didn't expect it to be the problem.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, and the default Nginx config for Elastic Beanstalk really should handle that better. However, Elastic Beanstalk does support single-instance configurations without a load balancer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was in the Nginx configuration as pointed out by @MarkB. AWS Elastic Beanstalk has a default configuration file `00_application.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk` that is the culprit. It has a declaration:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto     $scheme;
```

that needed to be changed to:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto     $http_x_forwarded_proto;
```

---

To overwrite this file, I used the method detailed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html.

I added a file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk` to the root of my deployed project. It contains:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade               $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection            $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header    Host                  $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto     $http_x_forwarded_proto;
}
```

---

I also had to add a middleware to my ASP.Net Core application to use the forwarded headers as noted in this answer: [Redirect URI sent as HTTP and not HTTPS in app running HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468033/redirect-uri-sent-as-http-and-not-https-in-app-running-https/50505373#50505373).

I added the following to my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
    //...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    //...
}
```

I hope this helps others!

Comment: For what it's worth, directly using that file content for `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk` seems to fail with an error: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here

Comment: The file needs to be name 00_application.conf and placed into the folder .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk

Comment: @Snickers is correct - the file is  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf` - confirmed that after AWS Toolkit right mouse publish that the `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf` file in your .Net proj overwrites the /etc/nginx file of the same name. Checked via SSH into the EC2 instance.